# Python return data for last 30 days

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I have this log file sample which i need to count entries for the last one month, three months and one year. Here are just some few lines of the log file

```
10/14/2015 10:04:25 AM Following file:<open file 'dirs/tmp/bundle_21241.dat.json', mode 'r' at 0x8b73498> has invalid json which is ignored
11/15/2015 10:42:53 PM Following file:<open file 'dirs/tmp/bundle_21241.dat.json', mode 'r' at 0xa314498> has invalid json which is ignored
10/21/2015 10:16:42 AM Following hmac:94e301ff67773de56194165451535ba223cd27588221363290fbfcb96d9d0539  with is already in database so dropping
11/21/2015 10:16:42 AM The data for the duplicate Hmac is : HF 13300100012015-06-15 19:11:47+0000+ 12.61 0.430  1686.00
10/21/2015 10:16:42 AM Following hmac:c35330404902c0b1bb5c6d0718407ea12b25a464433bd1e69152ccc0e0b89c9f  with is already in database so dropping
10/17/2015 10:16:42 AM The data for the duplicate Hmac is : HF 13300100012015-06-15 19:30:21+0000+ 12.61 0.010  1686.00
10/11/2015 10:16:42 AM Following hmac:8df71a9f6b6f0a0adb48c052767045f37ec34fce9c002a1c0c5ebc38ed500bf8  with is already in database so dropping
10/15/2015 10:16:42 AM The data for the duplicate Hmac is : HF 13300100012015-06-15 19:45:40+0000+ 12.61 0.018  1686.00
12/21/2015 10:16:42 AM Following hmac:fda9f5756461a8bc2922c55e75a31cf4915e6b0d016ecb786666624a0f04a02f  with is already in database so dropping
12/10/2015 10:16:42 AM The data for the duplicate Hmac is : HF 13300100012015-06-15 20:01:01+0000+ 12.60 0.048  1686.00
07/21/2015 10:16:42 AM Following hmac:84d9cdb2145b7c3e0fa2d099070b7bd291c652f30ca25c69240e33ebbd2b8677  with is already in database so dropping
```

Here is my code

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os

def fileCount(fileName):

    with open(fileName) as FileObj:

        Count = 0
        today_date = date.today()
        One_Year = str(today_date -  timedelta(days=365))
        One_Month = str(today_date -  timedelta(days=30))
        Three_Months = str(today_date -  timedelta(days=90))

        while True:

            line = FileObj.readline()

            record_date = ('-'.join(line[:10].split('/'))).split(" ")

            if not line:

                break

            if "Following hmac" in line:

                try:
                    convert_date = datetime.strptime(record_date[0], '%m-%d-%Y')

                    #print "Difference is ", todayDate -  convert_date.date()

                    #print convert_date.date()

                    date_diff = str(today_date - convert_date.date())

                    #print dateDiff[:8]

                    if date_diff[:8] < One_Month:

                        Count += 1

                        #print "Last 30 Days Failed HMAC is ", Count

                    else:

                        continue

                #print convert_date.date()

                except ValueError:

                    print 'This line has a problem:', record_date


        print "The Total Number of Failed HMAC is ", Count      

# Call The function
def main():

    filePath = 'file.txt'

    fileCount(filePath)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I am a newbie in programming and do not understanding date arithmetic well. Currently i am getting answers returned but they don't seems to be returning the correct values. The goal is to loop through each line and calculate the line count for the last 30, 60 and 365 days interval. My code currently include test for the last 30 days but i am getting a wrong value returned.

Comment: Your variable naming is bad. `OneMonth` should be named `one_month`, else it looks like a class name.

Comment: Thanks. I have made the necessary changes as requested.

Comment: If you have time, please read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thanks for the material. Do you have any idea about how to solve my problem above? i have made several changes but i am not getting the right count returned.

Comment: here's the hint: You're not comparing date objects with date objects, but string with string. `date_diff[:8] < One_Month` => How are you expecting to find which dates after the other? They are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert everything to a datetime object to be able to compare items. Also it would be easier to deal with all of the different ranges by defining them in a list and using a Python `Counter()` to count them accordingly. This would make it easier to extend the ranges.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import Counter


def fileCount(fileName):
    log_entry_counts = Counter()
    today = datetime.today()

    date_ranges = [
        ('three months', today - timedelta(days=90)),
        ('month', today - timedelta(days=30)),
        ('year', today - timedelta(days=365))]

    with open(fileName) as f_input:
        for line in f_input:
            if "Following hmac" in line:
                log_date = datetime.strptime(line[:10], '%m/%d/%Y')

                for text, dr in date_ranges:
                    if log_date >= dr:
                        log_entry_counts[text] += 1

    total = 0

    for text, count in log_entry_counts.items():
        print "Failed HMAC in the last {}: {}".format(text, count)
        total += count

    print "Total failed HMAC:", total

fileCount('input.txt')
```

Which would give you output looking something like:

```
Failed HMAC in the last three months: 1
Failed HMAC in the last month: 1
Failed HMAC in the last year: 2
Total failed HMAC: 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i am working very hard to understand these concepts and i know with time they will become easier